# Problem modelling address generalization

Tags: c#, sql, model, uml, entity-relationship

I’m a bit concerned about how to model this rather simple scenario the best way in UML and ERM. When designed it has to be implemented in C# (Entity Framework 4) and SQL Server 2008.

The case is that I have a person, who has a postal address. Now this address can be two types, either a postal box, or a house identifier (house number, street, etc.). I believe that this is called generalization, and might be modelled the following way using UML:

[http://i.imgur.com/Vzx4Z.png](https://i.imgur.com/Vzx4Z.png) (sorry for the link, but I don't have enough reputation to post images yet)

`PostalAddressPostalBox` and `PostalAddressHouseIdentifier` will of course have more properties and relations to other entities/tables. Same goes with the Person class. Also other classes will have a reference to a postal address, so it's not only persons.

My question is if this is the correct way to model this problem, and how I can implement it in SQL (schema wise) and what my entities in C# should look like?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

I just think you shouldn't reuse the `PostalAddress` for different entities. It will just be harder to change the address for a given entity.

For the relational database, there are some options, like [class table inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/classTableInheritance.html).

Or maybe [single table inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/singleTableInheritance.html) or [concrete table inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/concreteTableInheritance.html). It's up to you to decide the tradeoffs.